# SP for calculating the Average of every 2 rows

Tags: sql

I have a spreadsheet that contains a country code and its currency rate with respect to my country.
Each country code appears twice in the Excel sheet with 2 different values.
I want to get the average of the 2 values and save the average to the first row.
I was thinking of doing so by inserting the first row, reading the second row, and if the country code exists, do the average and save to the first, otherwise add the row to the list.
How is such feasible in SQL code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs, you could try:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET field1 = (field1 + field2)/2
```

**EDITED** (after reading your comment)
If you update only first row for every *CountryCode* you have another problem: second row remain there. So probably the best thing you could do is creating another table and fill it with correct values only:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (CountryCode, CurrencyRate)
SELECT CountryCode, AVG(CurrencyRate)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CountryCode
```

Comment: No, it comes in the format of 
CountryCode | CurrencyRate
A                  1
A                  2
B                  4
B                  3
etc...

Comment: @Adrian: and what do you want to do with every second row? Leave there? Delete? Probably creating a new table and inserting **only** correct values could be the right solution?

Comment: I was thinking of deleting the second row.

Comment: I hate to be so nagging, but how do I derive the currency rates and calculate their average based on having similar country code?

Comment: @Adrian: what do you mean with _similar_? Be careful, my question is not silly... Anyway your question was about adding when same country code was found...

Comment: If you have 80 countries in the excel sheet, each one has 2 currency rates. I want to take the currency rates, get their average, and save them to one record, in a new table as you said :)

Comment: @Adrian: ok, this is exactly what my query does: it takes same countries giving each currency average. But if you ask me to use _similar_ country codes, I ask you what do you mean with _similar_? Which algorithm do you want to use to check if two country codes are similar?

Comment: The application loads an excel sheet from the pc, and saves the data automatically in the database. But instead of saving with both currencyrates, I want it to save the average only. How is that feasible?

Comment: @Adrian: which language are you using? Show (editing your answer) the part of the code you use to open and read excel file

Comment: @Adrian - You should ask that to the person who developed that application. That has nothing to do with SQL. Marco showed you how it can be done *after* it is brought into a DBMS.

Comment: @Adrian - as you seem to be relatively new to SO, don't take this the wrong way but asking and answering so much in comments is a clear indication something was wrong with the question in the first place. It might be better to ask a new question with all the information required to *be able to* answer it (and it would be kind to accept Marco's response for this question).

Comment: @Lieven: Your comments are fair, thanks a lot! ...and with this I've just added another comment ;)

Comment: @Marco - don't mention it but it seems OP has left the building <g>